# Javascript update over too pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am busy with some coding, and I found something I wanted to do, but I couldn't find on the web.

I have a Index page, and a 'admin' page. On the Admin page I want to alter stuff, so it can be updated on the index screen. I know I can stuff my info in a VAR, but how do I move it across?

Here is my code as for now:

```
    <form action="set.php" method="POST" class="form 1">
<div class="phase">
Flight Phase:<br />
<select name="phase">
  <option value="noflight">-- No Flight --</option>
  <option value="depart">Departing</option>
  <option value="cruise">Cruizing</option>
  <option value="Decent">Decending</option>
</select>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="origin">
Origin:<br />
<input type="text" name="origin">
</div>

<div class="sign">
Sign:<br />
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="on">On
<input type="radio" name="sign" value="off">Off
</div>

<div class="dash">
-
</div>

<div class="dest">
Destination:
<input type="text" name="dest" >
</div>

<hr />
<br />
<div class="callsign">
Callsign:<br />
<input type="text" name="callsign">
</div>

<div class="aircraft">
Aircraft:<br />
<input type="text" name="aircraft">
</div>

<div class="airline">
Airline:<br />
<input type="text" name="airline">
</div>

<div class="network">
Network:<br />
<input type="text" name="network">
</div>

<div class="button">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Set!">
</div>

</form> 
</div>
```

All the DIV's has to do with the styling, I know it is the long way arround but yeah.
As you can see, my form is now direting to set.php. The set.php document updates my MYSQL database, I don't know wether this is the right way to do it, but on my index page nothing changes untill you refresh. I there a way arround?

Thanks!
Gidi

Comment: So you want to persist changes the admin makes to the index page, and I'm assuming only the admin can see? You'll need to use a combination of a database to persist the changes (recommended) and a session to ensure that only the logged in admin can see the changes on your index page.

Comment: Nope, I want that the admin can alter the info the user gets to see on the index page form a own enclosure

Comment: Learn what an [HTML Label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of having a hard time trying to understand what you are trying to do. You are asking for transferring a variable to another website, and saving some data from a form. Anyways.

About transferring variables across your website, there are multiple ways..

**PHP Sessions - The best way** (PHP SAMPLE)

In PHP, you can start a session which lets you store variables and will let you hold them for as long as the session runs. Here is an example of how a session is started, how you save a variable, and how you read it...

```
// We start a session, this usuallly runs before you serve any content
session_start();

// We assign some variables in the session array
$_SESSION['myName'] = "AlexKvazos";
$_SESSION['myAge'] = 16;

// Now, on other pages all you have to do is start a session and read the variables like this.

echo "Welcome to my website " . $_SESSION['myName'] . ", you are " . $_SESSION['myAge'] . " years old.";
```

**HTTP GET Variables // Okay if you want easier perm links** (PHP SAMPLE)

```
// If a URL is formed like this...
// http://mywebsite.com?name=Alex&age=16

// We can access those GET variables like this...
$name = $_GET['name'];
$age = $_GET['age'];
```

**HTTP Cookies // Also a smart way of doing it** (PHP SAMPLE)

```
// You can save data into a cookie like this:
setcookie('name', 'AlexKvazos');
setcookie('age', 16);

// Later on, we can access it like this:
$_COOKIE['name']; // AlexKvazos
$_COOKIE['age']; // 16
```

**HTML5 Local Storage // Not the smartest way unless you want to save settings for next visits and such** (JAVASCRIPT SAMPLE)

```
// Save a value into localStorage like this:
localStorage.name = 'AlexKvazos';
localStorage.age = 16;

//Then we can access them like this:
var name = localStorage.name;
var age = localStorage.age;
```

Comment: Given the wording of the question, this is the only thing i can think of too. However, I think you may want to provide an example of each.